# how to know workspace id/name with Xmonad

Tags: xmonad

I moved to Xmonad, which is a great tiling desktop manager.

Usually I launch many workspaces with Xmonad.

I often have some troubles to switch the workspace I would like to use.

please let me know how to show the workspace ID/number on Xmonad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xmonad itself doesn't provide any visual indication of the workspaces.
However, it provides information about the workspaces which can be displayed by using the statusbars [xmobar](http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/) or [dzen](https://github.com/robm/dzen).
The module [DynamicLog](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html) offers some possibilities how this information is  formatted.

If you don't know about yet, check out the [xmonad contribs](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/), which implement many cool layouts and functionality plain xmonad doesn't provide - the DynamicLog module is one of them.